# Read Excel data from dynamic column using pandas

Tags: python, xml, pandas, dataframe, automation

In my excel file header start from D5 and row star from D6.
column data type displayed in D4 cell onwards.

i want skip  data type row and first blank columns A,B,C and Read Actual excel data using python pandas.

[image]

Comment: It is not clear what the problem is. You should provide a [mcve].

Comment: @mzjn Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Try my code. so, you can move data table in excel sheet to anywhere.

```
filename = ["yourfile.xlsx"]
sheet = ["your sheetname"]
df = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=sheet, header=None)

# drop the columns and rows with all NaN's
df.dropna(axis=0, thresh=2, inplace=True)
df.dropna(axis=1, thresh=2, inplace=True)

# reset index to ensure first index is 0
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

# drop row NUMBER, CHAR and INTEGER
df.drop([0], inplace=True)
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

# get empno, ename and sal to set as header, then drop this data row
header = df.iloc[0]
df.columns = header
df.drop([0], inplace=True)
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Output

```
    empno   ename   sal
0   1       A       100
1   2       B       200
2   3       C       300
3   4       D       400
4   5       E       500
```

Comment: This deserves an answered.  You took practical ramblings of a question and answered it correctly.  This helped me so vm appreciated.